# Can a calculation in the SELECT clause execute before the WHERE predicate is applied?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can a calculation in the SELECT clause of a SQL query be executed  before the WHERE clause has been applied?  I am targeting SQL Server 2008 R2 but I am interested in general.  I assume this is covered by the SQL standard.

Take the following table and query:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
    ID bigint primary key,
    Accessed bigint null,
    Created bigint null,
    Modified bigint null
)

--insert the data here

SELECT ID, dateadd(ms, (Created % 864000000000) / 10000, dateadd(day, (Created / 864000000000) - 55517, '17530101')) AS EventTime, 3 AS EventType
FROM TestTable
WHERE (Created IS NOT NULL)
    AND (Created <> 0)
    AND (Created <= 2650467743999999999)
```

The WHERE predicate is intended to filter out values which would cause datetime overflow when passed through the nested dateadd() calls in the SELECT clause.  In some cases I still see the overflow happening even though I know for sure that the calculation will succeed on every value which satisfies the WHERE predicate. In every case of failure there are always some zero values in the source data.

My guess is that the query planner sometimes decides to do the calculation before applying the filter and thus allows in zero values which cause overflow.  I cannot confirm that because I can't see the execution plan when the overflow happens.

Is my theory sound?  Is there a way to confirm it?  I'm more interested in confirming the theory than anything else.  If my theory is correct then I know how to resolve the problem.

Comment: calculate will happen before `where` had similar issue where I filtered out bad data but calculation still failed, had to change to `TRY_CONVERT` instead of `CONVERT()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas, you cannot control when the filtering occurs.  SQL Server thinks it is doing you a favor by moving the `SELECT` calculation before the `WHERE` filtering in the actual execution plan.  Favors like this you don't need, because it results in an error.

There is a fix, which is to use the `case` statement:

```
SELECT ID,
       (case when Created <> 0 and Created < 2650467743999999999
             then dateadd(ms, (Created % 864000000000) / 10000, dateadd(day, (Created / 864000000000) - 55517, '17530101'))
        end) AS EventTime, 3 AS EventType
FROM TestTable
WHERE (Created IS NOT NULL) AND (Created <> 0) AND (Created <= 2650467743999999999);
```

If you don't like repeating conditions, you can put this in a subquery and test for `NULL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ID,
             (case when Created <> 0 and Created < 2650467743999999999
                   then dateadd(ms, (Created % 864000000000) / 10000, dateadd(day, (Created / 864000000000) - 55517, '17530101'))
              end) AS EventTime, 3 AS EventType
     FROM TestTable
    ) tt
WHERE EventTime is not null;
```

The `case` statement is guaranteed to evaluate the `when` clause before the `then`, although there are some peculiarities when it is used in the context of an aggregation.